# How to add items in listbox without duplicate Like That :

Tags: c#, visual-studio, listboxitem

[image]

I tried to show items without duplicate in List Box.

```
private void Lst_Box_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Chk_Multi.Checked == true)
    {
        Lst_Box.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiSimple;
        if (Lst_Box.SelectedItem == "Janvier")
        {
            Lst_Selected.Items.Add(Lst_Box.Text);
        }
    }
    if (Chk_Multi.Checked == false)
    {
        Lst_Box.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.One;
        Lst_Selected.Items.Add(Lst_Box.Text);
    }
}
```

Comment: write code that will search the Listbox using `.Contains()` method you need to check the value if it exist first before adding to the ListBox very simple task to do..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(!Lst_Selected.Items.Contains(Lst_Box.Text)
{
  Lst_selected.Items.Add(Lst_Box.Text);
}
```

Comment: Thank You it work successful

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `Except` extension method... example..

```
int[] foo = new int[]{1,2,3};
int[] bar = new int[]{1,3};

IEnumerable<int> fooMinusBar = foo.Except(bar);
IEnumerable<int> barMinusFoo = bar.Except(foo);
```

[image]